# SQL select same table, two different orders

Tags: mysql, sql

with mySQL, i have one table where are a lot of rows with products. Every product have columns with name, stock amount and date of last purchase. And i want to get result, where all products with stock amount more than 0 are sorted by name (this group first), and then all products with stock amount 0 are sorted by last purchase. So i cant use UNION because of two order definitions. Here are some data for better understanding:

**Table data:**
    Name | Stock | Last purchase
    -----------------------------
    Product 1 | 0  | 2014-09-20
    Product 2 | 10 | 2014-09-20
    Product 3 | 0  | 2014-09-26
    Product 4 | 10 | 2014-09-20
    Product 5 | 0  | 2013-08-18

**Needed result:**
Product 2 | 10 | 2014-09-20
Product 4 | 10 | 2014-09-20 ... these with stock more than zero order by name ASC
Product 1 | 0 | 2014-09-26
Product 3 | 0 | 2014-09-20
Product 5 | 0 | 2013-08-18 ... these with empty stock order by last purchase DESC

I need it as one result because of pagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an `order by` clause with multiple conditions:

```
order by (stock > 0) desc,
         (case when stock > 0 then name end) asc,
         (case when stock = 0 then lastpurchase end) desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the condition to your `ORDER BY`:

```
select * 
from data
order by stock > 0 desc, 
    if(stock>0,name,null) asc,
    if(stock>0,null,lastpurchase) desc
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c231d/5)